# Support of a function

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, terminology

What is the support of some function $F$ and why do we care about it? Is it of major significance for distribution functions?

Comment: Are you asking about the support of a function or of a distribution?

Comment: Hmm...what changes in this case?

Comment: They are two related but different concepts.  The support of a distribution is the smallest closed set to which it assigns all probability; the support of a function is the closure of the set where it is nonzero.  All distributions have (cumulative) distribution functions, but the supports of those functions are always unbounded intervals. When a distribution has a *density* with respect to Lebesgue measure (which is a special case), the support of the density coincides with the support of the distribution.

Comment: Where should I find more details? Some reference, a book or whatever... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Parts of the same Wikipedia page address these concepts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Support_of_a_distribution.  You ought to investigate the concept of support of a random variable, too.  For a discussion of all three, see the Math thread at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846011/precise-definition-of-the-support-of-a-random-variable.